# search video with javascript iframe api

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-api

I need the API which allows me to retrieve the url of a youtube video searching its title. Can anyone tell me where can I find it? I'm trying this with the 
"YouTube Player API Reference for  Embeds"

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Implementation of You tube search using pure Javascript in Github You can fork or download the repository to meet your needs

[Youtube Live search](https://github.com/lucasmonteverde/Youtube-Live-Search)

In the above implementation , it searches for title and description . and lists the videos along with urls , It also displays thumbnails ,  of the videos

I had reviewed this code It works perfect , only thing is It wont give you suggestions in the search box , I think even that is also possible if you fine tune a bit

Comment: I think That Option is not there , Let tell you once if i get that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the YouTube Data API's [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) interface for making search requests via JavaScript from any webpage. The documentation is at

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc

Here's an example URL that you can invoke via JSONP:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=myCallback&q=baseball

That will invoke the callback function `myCallback` with the first 25 search results matching the term `baseball`. The phrase you're searching for (`baseball` in that example) might appear in the title, description, or keywords of a video, so if you need to only display videos that have a matching title, you'll need to post-process the results from your own code.

The URL for the watch page of each entry is returned in the `player.default` property of each entry in the `items` array.